# Oracle SQL distinct Count(*) with 3 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to display 3 columns in a table.

Something like:

| ZIPCODE | SUBSCRIBERS | MEMBERS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 5 | 10 |
| 12346 | 3 | 8 |

In which each zipcode is a distinct zipcode that has a number of "subscribers" within it. The subscribers  would be the original employee, that can just be defined as DEPNO=0 (they are the original employee and not a dependent), the members would just be everyone in the zipcode which I am able to get with a statement that looks like the SQL below. I am pulling from a table called EMPDEP

`SELECT DISTINCT ZIPCODE, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ZIPCODE) as Subscribers FROM EMPDEP where depno=0`

This statement will get me a Subscriber count but I want the total member count in there as well which would just be

`SELECT DISTINCT ZIPCODE, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ZIPCODE) as Members FROM EMPDEP`

but getting all 3 of these in 1 query is killing me as I can't get the nesting down correctly, at least I'm assuming I will need that?

Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Huh?  Why are you using window functions?  Just use aggregation:

```
SELECT ZIPCODE, COUNT(*) as Members,
       SUM(CASE WHEN depno = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Subscribers
FROM EMPDEP 
GROUP BY ZIPCODE;
```

Comment: This is actually exactly what I'm looking for. Then when/else part of that is so clean. Thank you for the help!